# How to Flush Application Insights in a ILogger

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, console-application, azure-application-insights

I have a windows console application using application insights. I use the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` to set up my class and add the `ILogger`.

In a case of an exception I want to log this to Application Insights. But since Application Insights does send traces not immediately I want to Flush the log.

Is there an way to trigger the Flush of Application Insights behind a `ILogger`?

```cs
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceProvider serviceProvider = ConfigureServices();

            var program = serviceProvider.GetService<Program>();
            await program.Run();
        }

        public Program(ILogger<Program> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        private static ServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services
                .AddLogging(opt =>
                {
                    opt.AddConsole();
                    opt.AddApplicationInsights();
                })
                .AddTransient<Program>()
            return services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }

        public async Task Run()
        { 
            try
            {
                do.stuff()
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.LogError(e, "Exception occured");
                // How to flush Application insights here
                // Need to wait for Flush (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/console)
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#console-application This official doc has example which does Flush() for console application

Comment: @IvanYang Sorry for the delay. I got yesterday a busy day with unplanned work and want to try this first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try use the method `InMemoryChannel.Flush`, code sample as blow:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3netcore
{
    class Program
    {
        private readonly ILogger logger;
        static InMemoryChannel channel = new InMemoryChannel();

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceProvider serviceProvider = ConfigureServices();

            var program = serviceProvider.GetService<Program>();
            await program.Run();
        }

        public Program(ILogger<Program> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        private static ServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.Configure<TelemetryConfiguration>(
                (config) =>
                {
                    config.TelemetryChannel = channel;
                }
            );
            services
                .AddLogging(opt =>
                {
                    opt.AddConsole();
                    opt.AddApplicationInsights();
                })
                .AddTransient<Program>();
            return services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }

        public async Task Run()
        {
            try
            {
                throw new Exception("my exception 111");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.LogError(e, "Exception occured");
                // How to flush Application insights here
                channel.Flush();

                await Task.Delay(1000);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, got it working. I changed my code to do the flush and delay in finally block in the `Main` method. So it should also work for non exception termination.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This is the only good example I could find anywhere that actually follows a ServiceProvider pattern, versus instantiating the logger directly in the Main method.